# AngularJS : watching Service properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

Take the following plunk as an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vKFevXhhSprzFvesc6bG?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('SomeService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var service = {
        value: false
    }

    return service;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'SomeService', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.value = SomeService.value;

    //$scope.$watch(function () { return SomeService.value; }, function (data) { $scope.value = data; });
}]);

app.controller('SecondaryCtrl', ['$scope', 'SomeService', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.toggleValue = function () {
        SomeService.value = !SomeService.value;
    }
}]);
```

2 controllers and a service, 1 controller (SecondaryCtrl) updates a property on the service and the other controller (MainCtrl) references this property and displays it.

Note the $watch expression commented out in MainCtrl - with this line uncommented, everything works as expected but my question - is it necessary? Shouldn't the watch be implicit or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the value of SomeService.value to your scope variable, you are creating a copy of the variable which is a distinct object from the value inside SomeService. By adding the watch expression you were simply keeping the two variables (the one in the scope and the one in SomeService) synchronised.

The easiest way to go about this is not to copy the value, but create a reference to the service itself. So in MainCtrl

```
$scope.someService = SomeService;
```

and in your html

```
Value: {{someService.value}}
```

this way you are actually binding to the value inside SomeService.

Comment: Thanks! I should've thought of that.

Comment: @marco-sandrini Does this occur even when the value in SomeService is an object?

Comment: It should work if the object is replaced, but no change will be refreshed if the object is modified (but its reference remains the same). In other words if you replace the object with another object, the changes should be reflected, but if you simply change a property on the object, no refresh will occur.