# Angular watch issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's the first time I'm using Angular's watch function and apparently I don't get it to work.
I have a service called `apiService`, which has a variable `myFile`. I am injecting the service into my controller and want to watch the `apiService.myFile` value for a change. Unfortunately the watch only gets called on opening the webpage, not when the `apiService.myFile` variable actually changes. Here is the code for the watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return apiService.myFile}, function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    console.log("service changed: "+newVal +" : "+oldVal+" : "+ scope);
});
```

Why isn't it being called when `myFile`changes?

UPDATE 1: 
this is how I update the value of `apiService.myFile` inside the service

```
ApiService.prototype.uploadFile = function(fileContent) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/space_uploadFile/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            fileContent: fileContent
        },

        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        complete: function() {
          //called when complete
          console.log('process complete');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            this.myFile =data;
            console.log("this.myFile: "+this.myFile);
            console.log('process success');
       },
        error: function() {
          console.log('process error');
        },
      });

};
```

Comment: try adding `true` at the end to deep watch   `},true);`

Comment: what is your data type of 'apiService.myFile' ?

Comment: @cjmling adding true did not help

Comment: @JackPu it's a string returned from an ajax-request

Comment: have you tried using the value directly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872211/angularjs-watching-service-properties

Comment: Maybe you can try to add dirty check. eg: `},true);`

Comment: There's no need for putting in `true` here guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this inside a plunkr (as you didn't) and this works for me:

Sidenote: next time create an example demonstrating your problem (plunkr) so we can eliminate the case of your problem (e.g. typo).

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, apiService) {

  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    apiService.myFile += "!";
  };

  $scope.$watch(function(){return apiService.myFile}, function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    console.log("service changed: "+newVal +" : "+oldVal+" : "+ scope);
    $scope.someValue = newVal;
  });
});

app.service('apiService', function() {
  this.myFile = "Test";
});
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  {{someValue}}
  <button ng-click="changeValue()">Click</button>
</body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DpDCulalK1pZ8J0ykh2Z?p=preview

BTW: The $watch part is a copy from your question and it simply works for me.

Edit: Apparantly the OP was using $.ajax to do ajax calls and the value was updated inside the succeshandler (outside the Angular context). So there was no digest cycle triggered here. To fix this you should use the $http service provided by angular (or work your way around it without).

```
var self = this;
self.$http.post("/space_uploadFile/",
{ fileContent: fileContent },
{ 
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000
})
.then(function (data) {
    self.myFile = data;
    console.log("self.myFile: " + self.myFile);
    console.log('process success');
},
function () {
    console.log('process error');
});
```

Edit2: Apparantly the OP was also using `this` in the succeshandler to acces variable on the controller. This won't work, so I used the self pattern in the sample above to solve it.

Comment: if it simply works for you something is wrong in my controller then. Can it be because I do my ajax call inside the prototype of the service?
`ApiService.prototype.uploadFile = function(fileContent) {
 $.ajax({...]);};`

Comment: Use $http instead of $.ajax. Because you are leaving the Angular Context by using $.ajax hence changes happening inside the succeshandler won't trigger the angular's digest cycle.

Comment: I added the code of how I am actually changing the variable inside the service

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I have to use this.$http.post otherwise $http is not found. and then it's still only triggering the watch on pageload but not when the variable changes

Comment: Yes that's obvious but I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: So, is it working for you or are you still having problems ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123758/discussion-between-sumi-and-frederik-prijck).

Answer (score -3):

I am used to this syntax:

```
scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
});
```

where name is the name of your property - in this case `myFile`

Comment: This only works for properties on the scope. The OP doesn't want this. He want's to watch a property of a service.

Comment: then it might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables

Comment: so the answer is not to use angular watch but something else?

Comment: Actually you can use a $watch.

Comment: the angular watch is designed for watching changes in properties during the digest. It was simply not designed for services. My advice would be to implement a observer pattern in your service by yourself. that's what the linked answer suggests as well.

Comment: It actually is. Have a look at my plunkr .

Comment: Well, I stand corrected - thanks for clarification :)

Comment: Basicly there's 2 ways to $watch: using a string ( the property on the $scope) or a function returning anything, this function will be called on every digest cycle. The return value will be used to decide the value has changed or not by keeping track of the previously item returned from this list vs the currently returning value.